# Windows Phone - Using generic class for PhoneApplicationPage

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a Page which consist of AddPage.xaml and AddPage.xaml.cs. I want to create a generic class AddPage which extends from PhoneApplicationPage to outsource some repetitive code like Save or Cancel. 
If I change the base class from PhoneApplicationPage to my new generic class, I get this error: *Partial declarations of 'AddPage' must not specify different base classes.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To accomplish this you need to do the following.

First, create your base class

```
public class SaveCancelPhoneApplicationPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    protected void Save() { ... }
    protected void Cancel() { ... }
}
```

Then, your AddPage needs to be modified to inherit from the base class. The main places this is needed is within the code (AddPage.xaml.cs) AND within the xaml

Code:

```
public partial class AddPage : SaveCancelPhoneApplicationPage  {  ... }
```

Xaml:

```
<local:SaveCancelPhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="MyPhone.Namespace.AddPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyPhone.Namespace" 
       <!-- other xaml elements -->
</local:SaveCancelPhoneApplicationPage>
```

**UPDATE**: Info added based on comments

If you need to have generic like functionality and you must use the Page to do this (rather than a ViewModel) then you can still do this using generic methods

```
public abstract class SaveCancelPhoneApplicationPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(blaa,blaa)
    {
        var obj = CreateMyObject();
        obj.DoStuff();
    }

    // You should know what your objects are, 
    // don't make it usable by every phone dev out there
    protected MyBaseObject MyObject { get; set; }

    protected T GetMyObject<T>() where T : MyBaseObject 
    {
        return MyObject as T;
    }
}


public class AddPage : SaveCancelPhoneApplicationPage 
{
    public AddPage()
    {
        MyObject = new MyAddObject();
    }
}
```

Comment: My SaveCancelPhoneApplicationPage<T> is generic. How could I solve this in XAML because I need to pass the type argument?

Comment: Another problem: I get an exception 'Failed to assign to property 'Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ApplicationBarIconButton.Click'. [Line: 65 Position: 23]'. The problem seems to be that I can not use inherited methods for the applicatiobar's click event. If I override the methods, then it works! But why this strange behavior?

Comment: You cannot make it generic, xaml does not support this. Best bet is to make methods generic

Comment: Events must go directly to the top level class. You may want to go down the path of MVVM rather than classing PhoneApplicationPage. I know the (standard) appbar button does not allow for binding, but you could still have a click event that calls into the VM. There are also toolkits available that have bindable appbars

Comment: This sounds not good. I definitely need a generic class, because I need to create an object instance at run-time. Generic methods do not work because I want to override existing methods from *PhoneApplicationPage*.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I think that's the right answer to my question but it seems to be a little bit complex. Do you have any other ideas for my requirement. I want re-use code like parsing a ItemId from the query string and retrieving the Item from the ViewModel or localize application bar. A possible solution is a extension method, but I'm not sure if it is a good idea?

Comment: @c.z, making it use a generic class is very simple. Just create a solid class that extends your `GenericClass<YourSpecificType>` and use that. For example: `class GenericClass<TType> : PhoneApplicationPage` and then `class SolidClass : GenericClass<SolidType>`. Does this fit your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

In order to outsource some functions you  just declare some add class which does the common work. Having another page doesn't do that work.

```
public class Add
{
    public bool SaveContent(string filename, string content)
{
    ....//some content
    return true;
}

public string ViewContent(string filename)
{
    string content="";
    .....
    return content;
}
}
```

Add this part of code where you thought it is redundant.

```
Add obj=new Add();
obj.SaveContent("myfile.txt","Hello.This is my content.");
string content("myfile.txt");
```

Tell me if this is what you intend or not.

Comment: I want to inherit from a base clase, because I need to override methods like OnNavigatedTo etc.

Comment: If you want to eliminate the redundancy this will work.. I can't get your purpose.. And having created an object for a class like this, your page which created object can override the methods.

Comment: I know but it has some disadvantages. For example, I want to implement a method for localization of the appbar. In your way, I need to pass the appbar instance to the method. If I inherit from the class, I can simply call it without parameter passing. My purpose is a base class for my xaml pages, which implements some common methods like localization, saving...

Comment: @websocialist You want to extend a page for another page. then that page cannot be part of phone application. You cannot extend two classes.Or you are very much interested to make out pages, go for user controls which does that work. in either way you have to make out instances or references.